# how to extract the string and println after get the result from sql query

Tags: java, sql, groovy

I have written codes to query result from database using GroovyRowResult:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table.A"
println(Query.get(0).get('testid'))
```

the query result is

```
[num_slashes:exam, testid:64]
```

I have lines of code:

```
def countA = appitems.size()
println(countA)
```

I want to assert the CountA == SQL query result testid 64.
How do i extract the integer value 64 from the SQL query result?

Comment: Using uppercase variable names is not idiomatic groovy. It's even possible the parser gets confused and assumes a class.

Comment: @cfrick what's your recommendation?

Comment: Using variable names starting with lowercase characters

Comment: Thanks. I modified to have lowercase always.

Answer (score 0):

GroovyRowResult use get(0) to get the first record then convert it to string as it is object.

To get the value at 'testid' use '.' after get(0)

def query = "SELECT * FROM table.A"
println(query.get(0).testid.toString())

def countitems = appitems.size()
println(countitems)

assert countitems == query.get(0).testid

Comment: From review: This answer is missing some context and explanation. Please edit to explain your solution.